# This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions ^16.0.0, but Angular version 10.2.5 was found instead

Tags: angular

[current version installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYWI7.png)I tried uninstalling cli and cleaned cache and install, still getting the same error.

npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm i -g @angular/cli

npm cache clean --force

Also, tried removing package json lock and nodemodules folder and tried installing again, no luck so far. Please help

Comment: So you uninstalled/reinstalled the CLI -- did you uninstall/reinstall angular as well?

Comment: "devDependencies": {

    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.2.1",

    "@angular/cli": "^16.2.1",

    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^10.2.4",

    "@angular/language-service": "^10.2.4",

Comment: what command should I use to uninstall/reinstall angular?

Answer (score 0):

What version are you trying to upgrade to?

I'll just assume you want to update to 16.2.1 based on your comment.

Try **npm install @angular/cli@16.2.1 --save-dev**

then proceed with

1. rm -r .\node_modules\
2. rm -r .\package-lock.json
3. npm i

and compile your angular project again

Also check out this [Compatibility Matrix](https://gist.github.com/LayZeeDK/c822cc812f75bb07b7c55d07ba2719b3#file-angular-cli-node-js-typescript-rxjs-compatiblity-matrix-csv-L15) to ensure all of your dependencies are compatible

Comment: version check shows Angular CLI 16.2.1
Angular 10.2.5
Need to upgrade Angular to 16.2.1   Tried above steps and it goes to where I started. Will try again